# How to report code coverage in Github Pull Requests using Sonar Github plugin

Tags: github, sonarqube

I have SonarQube server 5.6 and I am using Github. I have done the integration to setup Sonar Github plugin but I fail to understand whether this should report if the new code does not meet the code coverage threshold setup in the Quality Gate.

In the Quality Gate I have defined an error to be raised unless there is more than 75% code coverage for the new code that is being introduced by a Pull Request.

1. Should the Sonar Github plugin report an issue (comment) in Github pull request if the new code added does not meet the Quality Gate metric that I setup?
2. Is there any way to mark in Github Pull Requests if the new code trying to be merged does not meet the coverage expectations?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) first?

Comment: @JeroenHeier The documentation doesn't mention coverage at all - I'd argue this is worthy of more than a passive aggressive answer.

Answer (score 7):

Pull request analysis cannot currently raise *all* types of issues. Specifically it cannot raise issues related to metrics because those are consolidated on the server side during analysis report processing and in a Pull Request analysis the analysis report is by design never submitted to the server.

**EDIT** The PR analysis which is offered as part of the Developer Edition($) *does* both decorate the PR in the provider (e.g. GitHub) *and* show the PR on the server. However, metric-related issues *still* don't show up in this enhanced analysis.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! So currently I do not have a way to reflect in Github Pull Requests if the metric "Lines should have sufficient coverage by unit tests" fails?Or is there any other solution that Sonar offers so that I get a git commit status fail in Pull Requests if the new code that was added does not meet the coverage criteria in a Java project?

Comment: Nope. That's a metric-related rule, so it can't raise issues during PR analysis.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Is that something supported in the Developer/Enterprise versions of SonarQube since it looks like it uses your branch analysis path for PRs?